# Can thrust deal with half precision floats (float16 / IEEE 754-2008)?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I'm looking at an application that does not require 32bit of precision, 12-16bit will be enough.

Is thrust capable of dealing with float16's (i.e. packing/unpacking two 16bit precision floats into a 32bit word)?

Should I use fixed-point arithmetic?

Comment: Cuda doesn't have 16 bit floating point arithmetic support. You can load half floats and cast to single precision in a single operation, but that is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA hardware does not include native support for `half`-precision arithmetic, only conversion to and from `float`.

Since C does not have a built-in `half` type, the conversion intrinsics use `unsigned short`:

```
unsigned short __float2half_rn( float );
float __half2float( unsigned short );
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here is now out of date.

Cuda 7.5 now has support for 16-bit floats.

Include the header `cuda_fp16.h` for the `half` and `half2` data types.